# Make figure with minipages wider than text

Tags: floats, minipage

I have a lot of figures I want to present, and I try to line them up three in a row to save space, using the code below.

The figures become a bit too small, so I wanted to make the outer figure 1.25 of `textwidth` by putting `{1.25\textwidth}` after `\begin{figure}`, but that gives me a "Missing number, treated as zero." error.

How can I make the figure wider?

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{minipage}{.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{survey-q1.eps}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{survey-q2.eps}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{survey-q3.eps}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Answers to questions 1, 2, and 3.}
    \label{fig:survey-ans-1-2-3}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: This has been asked in various forms a number of times.  Here's two: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308637/fit-a-very-wide-table-on-the-page, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388786/changing-margins-so-a-table-fits-in-current-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I use nested `\makebox`es around the `minipage`s.  The outer one set to `\textwidth`, so that it centers properly, the inner to `1.25\textwidth` to allow the `\hfill`s to operate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \makebox[\textwidth]{\makebox[1.25\textwidth]{%
    \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{survey-q1.eps}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{survey-q2.eps}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{survey-q3.eps}
    \end{minipage}}}
    \caption{Answers to questions 1, 2, and 3.}
    \label{fig:survey-ans-1-2-3}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `adjustwidth` environment from `changepage`, in this way:

```
\usepackage{changepage}
      .......
\begin{document}
      .......
\begin{adjustwidth}{-0.125\textwidth}{-0.125\textwidth}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
    \begin{minipage}{.33\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{survey-q1.eps}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.33\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{survey-q2.eps}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.33\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{survey-q3.eps}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Answers to questions 1, 2, and 3.}
    \label{fig:survey-ans-1-2-3}
\end{figure}
\end{adjustwidth}
  .......
```

Don't forget to replace `\textwidth` with `\linewidth` for the minipages.