# Center table that is wider than \textwidth

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, margins

I have a table that is wider than the `\textwidth` of my document. I don't want to change the `\textwidth` nor the width of the table. As a result, the leftmost part of the figure is flush with the left margin, while the rightmost part spills into the right margin. I'd like to center the table, so that it will exceed the `\textwidth` equally on both sides.

I'm searching for the simplest possible solution.

Comment: This question has appeared in various ways before, for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308637/fit-a-very-wide-table-on-the-page, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388786/changing-margins-so-a-table-fits-in-current-page, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306514/how-to-align-table-so-that-it-doesnt-overflow-the-page-horizontally

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)